# Transfer from EtherCamp to local geth does not work (testnet) - Balance is Zero

Tags: mining, accounts, testnets, ether-camp, wallet-transfer

I am playing around with Ethereum testnet.

I created an account at https://test.ether.camp/. I received free Ether and sent 1 Ether to an account address on my local geth client, which I created on my Macbook with the following commands:

> geth --fast --cache=2048 --testnet console

(..... after it finished synchronizing .....)

> personal.newAccount("###_my_passphrase_###")

This is the only account I have here.

The EtherCamp account address is 0xd2812d264e9895e8c31122aaffedb6f444c1a2d0.
The transaction is completed successfully.

However, I only see '0' when asking for my balance:

> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")
>   web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0]), "ether")

Now, I started mining for ~15 minutes ago with

> miner.start(2)

It still shows '0' even though I read that you should get some Ether relative quickly.

Therefore, I wonder If I check the wrong balance !? Or does my local geth client use another testnet than EtherCamp?

UPDATE: 
I found out that I am on the right testnet, because I also sent me one Ether via http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/. This worked and after a few minutes I received the one Ether. My balance is 1 now.
I doublechecked via EtherScan that this is the Ether from faucet: https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x4dee8036ac3df3d6ab68126d109a6df3de54aff674230bd4e2dd605acb37e890 
Therefore, I really wonder why I do not get my Ether from EtherCamp (and also none via mining yet).

Thanks for help.